# Load a groovy script with a class name different from the file name

Tags: groovy, classloader

I load a groovy script this way

```
CompilerConfiguration configuration = new CompilerConfiguration()
GroovyClassLoader cLoader = new GroovyClassLoader (this.class.classLoader, configuration)
gse = new GroovyScriptEngine(scriptRoots, cLoader)
gse.setConfig(configuration)
Class scriptClass = gse.loadScriptByName('Unsuitable-Script-Name.groovy')
```

The problem is that the script is loaded with the same class name as the file name (`Unsuitable-Script-Name`). And it can be a problem if a file name contains dashes ([GROOVY-7670](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7670))

Can I somehow load the script with custom class name without renaming a file?

Comment: Rather obscure problem you have there. What is so wrong with the name. Mostly, nobody cares about the mostly anonymous class in there..

Comment: @NielsBechNielsen, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7670